# Swift Compiler Version Conflict

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

This question is similar to

[Swift Version Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659085/swift-version-conflict-this-sdk-is-not-supported-by-the-compiler-using-build)

The only difference is the configuration below

Xcode 14.2 (Swift compiler 5.7.2)
iOS Deployment target 16.2
Build library for distribution YES

I have updated my swift version on my package

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.7.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SmileIDentity",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v16)],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SmileIDentity",
            targets: ["SmileIDentity", "Smile_Identity_SDK"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SmileIDentity",
            dependencies: []),
        .binaryTarget(name: "Smile_Identity_SDK", path: "./Smile_Identity_SDK.xcframework"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SmileIDentityTests",
            dependencies: ["SmileIDentity"]),
        
    ]
)
```

But I get the error

```
Failed to build module 'Smile_Identity_SDK'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.7.1 (swiftlang-5.7.1.135.3 clang-1400.0.29.51)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.
```

Comment: Not your fault. The developers of `Smile_Identity_SDK` need to learn to build their packages properly for distribution (here's what in a nutshel they should do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58656323/5318223). All you can do is either ask them for new version that supports this version you want, or use the version they created their SDK with.